# How do I parse a List JSON File in CSV into a dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
[{"Apertura":35,"Apertura_Homogeneo":35,"Cantidad_Operaciones":1,"Cierre":35,"Cierre_Homogeneo":35,"Denominacion":"INSUMOS AGROQUIMICOS S.A.","Fecha":"02\/02\/2018","Maximo":35,"Maximo_Homogeneo":35,"Minimo":35,"Minimo_Homogeneo":35,"Monto_Operado_Pesos":175,"Promedio":35,"Promedio_Homogeneo":35,"Simbolo":"INAG","Variacion":-5.15,"Variacion_Homogeneo":0,"Vencimiento":"48hs","Volumen_Nominal":5},
{"Apertura":34.95,"Apertura_Homogeneo":34.95,"Cantidad_Operaciones":2,"Cierre":34.95,"Cierre_Homogeneo":34.95,"Denominacion":"INSUMOS AGROQUIMICOS S.A.","Fecha":"05\/02\/2018","Maximo":34.95,"Maximo_Homogeneo":34.95,"Minimo":34.95,"Minimo_Homogeneo":34.95,"Monto_Operado_Pesos":5243,"Promedio":-79228162514264337593543950335,"Promedio_Homogeneo":-79228162514264337593543950335,"Simbolo":"INAG","Variacion":-0.14,"Variacion_Homogeneo":-0.14,"Vencimiento":"48hs","Volumen_Nominal":150},
{"Apertura":32.10,"Apertura_Homogeneo":32.10,"Cantidad_Operaciones":2,"Cierre":32.10,"Cierre_Homogeneo":32.10,"Denominacion":"INSUMOS AGROQUIMICOS S.A.","Fecha":"07\/02\/2018","Maximo":32.10,"Maximo_Homogeneo":32.10,"Minimo":32.10,"Minimo_Homogeneo":32.10,"Monto_Operado_Pesos":98756,"Promedio":32.10,"Promedio_Homogeneo":32.10,"Simbolo":"INAG","Variacion":-8.16,"Variacion_Homogeneo":-8.88,"Vencimiento":"48hs","Volumen_Nominal":3076}]
```

Hi,

in the same example as above, if I do get a CSV file with that data Arpertura.csv, how can I import and parse it in a PANDAS dataframe? The real file is a few gigabytes large. I want to get
Sum Volumen_Nominal for all Aperturas (3076+150+5) and some other slice and dice.

Thanks.
Chibi

I tried importing the CSV with

```
df = pd.read_csv(r\'filename')
df_json = df.to_JSON()

pd.read_json(_, orient='split')
```

but it would not work. I think the list structure in front has to be removed.

The result I now gets is
Header = `[{"Apertura":35,"Apertura_Homogeneo":35,"Cantidad_Operaciones":1,"Cierre":35,"Cierre_Homogeneo":35,"Denominacion":"INSUMOS AGROQUIMICOS S.A.","Fecha":"02\/02\/2018","Maximo":35,"Maximo_Homogeneo":35,"Minimo":35,"Minimo_Homogeneo":35,"Monto_Operado_Pesos":175,"Promedio":35,"Promedio_Homogeneo":35,"Simbolo":"INAG","Variacion":-5.15,"Variacion_Homogeneo":0,"Vencimiento":"48hs","Volumen_Nominal":5}`

Body starts with **nan** and follows with the rest:

`{"Apertura":34.95,"Apertura_Homogeneo":34.95,"Cantidad_Operaciones":2,"Cierre":34.95,"Cierre_Homogeneo":34.95,"Denominacion":"INSUMOS AGROQUIMICOS S.A.","Fecha":"05\/02\/2018","Maximo":34.95,"Maximo_Homogeneo":34.95,"Minimo":34.95,"Minimo_Homogeneo":34.95,"Monto_Operado_Pesos":5243,"Promedio":-79228162514264337593543950335,"Promedio_Homogeneo":-79228162514264337593543950335,"Simbolo":"INAG","Variacion":-0.14,"Variacion_Homogeneo":-0.14,"Vencimiento":"48hs","Volumen_Nominal":150}`

Comment: if you're able to read the file (ie. your system has enough memory), you might be able to just take the first list entry .. but if you're starting with a CSV, there could be no need to rewrite the file as JSON intermediately

Comment: Yes, the memory is fine. Problem is that the first row of that data is taken as a header instead of just the column names. (see my comment below).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to convert the dataframe to json and back.
If you want the sum of a column you can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'filename')
df["Volumen_Nominal"].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks @chepner. Problem is that when I add it to the df and do a df.head() I get:  [{"Apertura":35, ....  :5}  as the HEADER and  nan [{"Apertura":34.95, ....  :150} as the next lines

Comment: @Chibigund Not my answer; I only fixed a small typo.